# Regular expression to find two strings anywhere in input

Tags: regex, string

How do I write a regular expression to match two given strings, at any position in the string?

For example, if I am searching for `cat` and `mat`, it should match:

```
The cat slept on the mat in front of the fire.
At 5:00 pm, I found the cat scratching the wool off the mat.
```

No matter what precedes these strings.

Comment: how about `"catmat"` - should the regex match it? should those words be whole words? How about `"scathing matters"`

Comment: No, it should not match either of those.
Just those two words, in that order, preceded and followed by any other text.

Comment: Please see my edit if you are using my code.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
/^.*?\bcat\b.*?\bmat\b.*?$/m
```

Using the `m` modifier (which ensures the beginning/end metacharacters match on line breaks rather than at the very beginning and end of the string):

- `^` matches the line beginning
- `.*?` matches anything on the line before...
- `\b` matches a word boundary the first occurrence of a word boundary (as @codaddict discussed)
- then the string `cat` and another word boundary; note that underscores are treated as "word" characters, so `_cat_` would *not* match*;
- `.*?`: any characters before...
- boundary, `mat`, boundary
- `.*?`: any remaining characters before...
- `$`: the end of the line.

It's important to use `\b` to ensure the specified words aren't part of longer words, and it's important to use non-greedy wildcards (`.*?`) versus greedy (`.*`) because the latter would fail on strings like "There is a cat on top of the mat which is under the cat." (It would match the last occurrence of "cat" rather than the first.)

* If you want to be able to match `_cat_`, you can use:

```
/^.*?(?:\b|_)cat(?:\b|_).*?(?:\b|_)mat(?:\b|_).*?$/m
```

which matches either underscores *or* word boundaries around the specified words. `(?:)` indicates a non-capturing group, which can help with performance or avoid conflicted captures.

Edit: A question was raised in the comments about whether the solution would work for phrases rather than just words. The answer is, absolutely yes. The following would match "A line which includes both the first phrase and the second phrase":

```
/^.*?(?:\b|_)first phrase here(?:\b|_).*?(?:\b|_)second phrase here(?:\b|_).*?$/m
```

Edit 2: If order doesn't matter you can use:

```
/^.*?(?:\b|_)(first(?:\b|_).*?(?:\b|_)second|second(?:\b|_).*?(?:\b|_)first)(?:\b|_).*?$/m
```

And if performance is really an issue here, it's possible lookaround (if your regex engine supports it) might (but probably won't) perform better than the above, but I'll leave both the arguably more complex lookaround version and performance testing as an exercise to the questioner/reader.

Edited per @Alan Moore's comment. I didn't have a chance to test it, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: `[\b]` matches a **backspace**, not a word boundary; `\b` takes on a different meaning inside a character class.

Comment: @Alan Moore, thanks for the tip. The way things change meaning in a character class always throws me for a loop.

Comment: For matching any characters before, `.*` seems like it should be preferred to `.*?` which prefers matching as few characters as possible, and might unnecessarily limit the amount of matches.

Comment: Wow, so many great usernames in this one thread. @AlanMoore I'm a huge fan of your work.

Comment: What is expected from `/m`? Why is this needed? When testing it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), I have complains.

Comment: In PerlRegex modifier is (?m)(?i)  etc.

Answer (score 38):

```
(.* word1.* word2.* )|(.* word2.* word1.*)
```

Comment: -1: incorrectly matches "a catastrophic mattress", fails on "cat on the mat" and doesn't observe word order (although that was specified only in the comments).

Comment: add the word boundaries so there are not substring matches

Comment: This may not match what OP wanted but it helped me find two strings in a URL so +1

Comment: And if the order is always the same and you don't care about spaces surrounding the words, you can use `(.*word1.*word2.*)` Simple and sweet and works very well for tricky Find Alls in things like Sublime Text, VSCode, etc that support REGEX searching.

Answer (score 7):

You can try:

```
\bcat\b.*\bmat\b
```

`\b` is an *anchor* and matches a *word boundary*. It will look for **words** cat and mat anywhere in the string with mat following cat. It will not match:

`Therez caterpillar on the mat`.

but will match

`The cat slept on the mat in front of the fire`

If you want to match strings which have **letters** cat followed by mat, you can try:

```
cat.*mat
```

This will match both the above example strings.

Comment: Hmm.. not quite. It didn't match either string perfectly.
It did match the "cat ... mat" pattern, but not the part before and after it.

Comment: Oh ok..if he wants search cat and mat as *words*, you can add word boundary. Thanks Phanindra K.

Comment: Thanks codaddict.
I modified the regex to be something like this: .*?cat.*?mat.*?
I hope that won't have any unwanted side effects. :)

Comment: What if one of the words was not a "word" but a phrase (words with spaces in between)?
Would this still work?

Comment: Did you mean something like "ca t on a mat" ??

Comment: @Phanindra K:  open up another question; as you are now describing a different problem than what you have written above.

Comment: @Adam Bernier and @Phanindra, an adequate solution to this question ought to be an adequate solution to the question raised in comments. No other post should be necessary.

Comment: Word order doesn't matter according to the question.

Answer (score 7):

If you absolutely need to only use one regex then

```
/(?=.*?(string1))(?=.*?(string2))/is
```

i modifier = case-insensitive

.*? Lazy evaluation for any character (matches as few as possible)

?=  for Positive LookAhead it has to match somewhere

s modifier = .(period) also accepts line breaks

Answer (score 5):

This is fairly easy on processing power required:

`(string1(.|\n)*string2)|(string2(.|\n)*string1)`

I used this in visual studio 2013 to find all files that had both string 1 and 2 in it.

Comment: Great! But how can I avoid whitespace and other non-word characters in between. I am trying to find all mix of whole words with the words 'student' and 'name'. So "studentpreferredname" and "student_name" are ok, but not "StudentID=@StudentID ORDER BY q.QualificationName"

Comment: @Mike Socha III, how would you modify this so that it only finds strings that do NOT have *both* string1 and string2?

Comment: Super, tried to match two words and one and only one sign [:] in between:
(?i)(\bVar\b(.*?:{1}\s*)\bWord\b)'
match: var Year,  Month, Day: Word
should not: var Year: int;  Month, Day: Word

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use regex. In your favourite language, split on spaces, go over the splitted words, check for cat and mat. eg in Python

```
>>> for line in open("file"):
...     g=0;f=0
...     s = line.split()
...     for item in s:
...         if item =="cat": f=1
...         if item =="mat": g=1
...     if (g,f)==(1,1): print "found: " ,line.rstrip()

found:  The cat slept on the mat in front of the fire.
found:  At 5:00 pm, I found the cat scratching the wool off the mat.
```

Comment: this also matches mat before cat, which is what the question asks, but may not be the intent :)

Comment: The problem that regex solves in this case is having quite a lot more flexibility over what to consider a boundary. Considering only spaces to be boundaries, this would fail (even though it seems the questioner's intent to have it match): `Beware the cat; it lays on the mat.` And while regex may be slower than the equivalent code to do this more safely, the equivalent code could require dozens of lines of code to do it right. There's a justified caution on SO about regex, but it really is the appropriate tool for this job.

Comment: its also easy to strip off punctuations if punctuations are not needed, without regex

Answer (score 0):

This works for searching files that contain both `String1` and `String2`

```
(((.|\n)*)String1((.|\n)*)String2)|(((.|\n)*)String2((.|\n)*)String1)
```

Match any number of characters or line fields
followed by `String1`
followed by any number of characters or line fields
followed by `String2`
OR
Match any number of characters or line fields
followed by `String2`
followed by any number of characters or line fields
followed by `String1`

Comment: Hi, for the same very first example cat and mat.

could you advise how to perform negative regex find. for instance. if I find cat and mat in a line. I should ignore that line. but if find cat with anything else I should capture that. So below send line cat with carpet should be considered.

`The cat slept on the mat in front of the fire.`

`At 5:00 pm, I found the cat scratching the wool off the carpet`