# matching lines in vi that contain any permutation of a set of strings

Tags: regex, perl, vim

I am trying to search for lines that contain any permutation of a group of words (case-insensitively). For example, if I am interested in the words `foo` and `bar`, I would want to match the first four lines but not the last four lines in the following `file`:

```
Foo and bar.
Bar and foo.
The foo and the bar.
The bar and the foo.
Foobar.
Barfoo.
The foobar.
The barfoo.
```

Having looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2219830/873757), I realize I can construct something like this in `perl`:

```
perl -n -e 'print if (/\bfoo\b.*?\bbar\b/i || /\bbar\b.*?\bfoo\b/i)' file
```

which correctly matches only the first four lines. Alternatively, using a look-ahead construct as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469913/873757), the match can be made with slightly more concise code:

```
perl -n -e 'print if (/(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)/i)' file
```

I cannot, however, figure out how to write these in `vim` regex syntax, which I find to be far more byzantine than `perl` regex syntax. I have tried many different expressions in `vim` using the search function (`/` or `?`), but none of them produce successful matches. I realize that instead of the `(?=string)` syntax used by `perl`, `vim` uses `\(string\)\@=` and `string\&`.

However, a variety of attempts, e.g.:

- `\c\(foo\)\@=\(bar\)@=`
- `\c\(foo\)\@=\.*\(bar\)@=`
- `\cfoo\&bar\&`

(where `\c` is used for a case-insensitive match) have all been unsuccessful.

Could someone please demonstrate the correct `vim` syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `\c.*\<foo\>.*\&.*\<bar\>.*`. This should match the whole of each of the first four lines.

You were closest with `\c\(foo\)\@=\(bar\)@=`, but since you don't want e.g. `foobar`, `barfoo` to match it's necessary to use begin/end of word matching: `\<\>`.

Using `\&` simplifies the pattern a bit.

If you don't need the *whole* line matches from that pattern, just a hit on any line that matches, you can simplify this regex a bit more by killing the trailing `.*` pieces in the pattern: `\c.*\<foo\>\&.*\<bar\>`

Comment: Thanks, both of those match correctly and only once per line.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
/^\c\(.*\<foo\>\)\@=\(.*\<bar\>\)\@=/
```

This is the same thing as the lookahead version from Perl, `\@=` makes the previous element or group a positive lookahead.  `\<` and `\>` are the vim equivalent to `\b`, and `\c` enables case insensitive matching.  I added the `^` anchor so it will match each line only once.

Comment: Thanks, the `^` anchor was very helpful because without it, each character in the line was counted as a unique match. Could you also tell me how to add an optional suffix? Say, I wanted to match barring and barred. I realize I could omit the word end boundary (`/^\c\(.*\<foo\>\)\@=\(.*\<bar\)\@=/`), but what if I did not want to match bars. Is there a way to match something like `\<bar(ed|ing)\>`?

Comment: close, but more escaping: `\<bar\(ed\|ing\)\>`