# Find all lines in a file that have two strings on the same line

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression that will work with the following dummy input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit -V amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Aenean commodo ligula Charge Tip eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.
Nascetur ridiculus Charge Tip mus. Donec quam felis,-Vultricies nec.
Pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa.
Quis enim. DonecCharge Tippede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec.-V
Vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut.
```

And produce the following result:

```
Charge Tip -V
Charge Tip -V
```

Some notes:

- Charge Tip is always before -V
- Charge Tip may be attached to other data on the left and right.
- -V may be attached to other data on the left and right

I tried many links here already, such as:
[Regular expression to find two strings anywhere in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219830/regular-expression-to-find-two-strings-anywhere-in-input)

I was unable to get any solution to work as the solutions fail to work on the RegExr site, which I am using to test the regex.

The final result I need is for the regex to work inside Agent Ransack 2014, as I need to search log files on a Windows XP machine.

Comment: Is this what you want https://regex101.com/r/OjdUd2/1 ? Matches are in capture group 1 and 2.

Comment: Use `(?-s)Charge Tip(?=.*-V)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agent Ransack regex engine is Perl compatible. So you can easily search for:

```
(?-s)Charge Tip(?=.*-V)|(?!\A)\G.*\K-V
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/qEhziC/2)

Comment: Thank you. If possible, please modify it slightly to highlight the -V, as there are many lines with charge Tip without -V, and your solution looks like Charge Tip only.

Comment: You're welcome. You may consider up-voting this answer as well if it helped you.

Comment: Done. It most certainly did.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex, you can see it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/Fwzvbn/2):

```
^[\w \,\.]*(Charge Tip)[\w \,\.]*(\-V)[\w \,\.]*$
```

As seen here:

[image: Regex101]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give any matches, on regex101 or regexr.

Comment: @wickyd can you please explain where it doesn't match? See my edit for what I see on Regex101.

Comment: @wickyd Looks like it didn't save correctly. See the `g` on the far right of the regex line, if you add an `m` (multiline) it should work. IE: `/^[\w \,\.]*(Charge Tip)[\w \,\.]*(\-V)[\w \,\.]*$/gm`

Comment: This way you highlight whole line in Agent Ran. not just `Charge Tip` and `-V`

Comment: @revo I'm not sure what you are talking about? The regex will provide two matches - "Charge Tip" and "-V".

Comment: No it doesn't. It matches *whole line* and *captures* `Charge Tip` and `-V` accordingly

Comment: The question asks to produce the `Charge Tip -V` result. This can be done with `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: Where in Agent Ran. should OP use these back-references? Is he trying to do a find / replace? Does the program provide a find / replace functionality at all?