# Matching a word followed by another word anywhere on page

Tags: regex, search, phpstorm

I have a files that shows the locale that the file is placed. So need to find when the file contains a certain locale and has a certain word in it.The word maybe anywhere on the page.

Regex

```
/^.*?\b(uk_en)\b.*?\bneedle\b.*?$/m
```

Example

```
id: page_name
locale: uk_en
----
<div> placeholder placeholder  placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder</div>
<span>placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder placeholder  </span>
<p>Needle</p>
```

My reference for the regex
[Regular expression to find two strings anywhere in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219830/regular-expression-to-find-two-strings-anywhere-in-input)

Link to test
https://regex101.com/r/dFdQl3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the multiline flag. What you instead need is the single line flag. Also note that your regex contains `needle` but your string contains `Needle`, so you need the insensitive flag as well.

```
/\b(uk_en)\b.*?\bneedle\b/si
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/pIEnRb/1)